# angular 5 - add class only if element exists in array

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-class

While using `ng-for` loop, I want to add class to item, only if the id of the item exists in some other objects list.

I tried something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let p of products" [class.Flag]="favoriteList.some((item)=> item.Id == p.id)"> </div>
```

or this:

```
<div *ngFor="let p of products" [ngClass]="favoriteList.some((item)=> item.Id == p.id) ? 'Flag': ''"> </div>
```

But it's not compiling.

note that the "favoriteList" may be load to the page **after** "products".

Any idea how can I do this?

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

problem is in your **some()** method,

Here's is an example

`component.html`

```
<div *ngFor="let p of products" [class.Flag]="someMethod(p.id)"> {{p.name}} 
</div>
```

`component.css`

```
.Flag { background: red; }
```

and `component.ts`

```
 products = [
          {"id": 1 , name: 'abc'}, 
          {"id": 2 , name: 'xyz'}
        ];

  favoriteList = [
          {"id": 1 , name: 'test'}, 
          {"id": 3 , name: 'test1'}
        ];

  someMethod(id){
    return this.favoriteList.some((item) => item.id == id);
  }
```

here is [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dm5ptn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) demo.

Answer (score 1):

use `ng-container` in order to access template variable in `div` for class as:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let p of products">
    <div [ngClass]="getClass(p.id)">{{p.name}}</div>
</ng-container>

getClass(id) {
    return this.favoriteList.some(item => item.Id == id) ? 'Flag':'';
}
```

Find stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3kthqw)

**Solution 2:**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let p of products">
    <div [ngClass]="{'flag': p.favourite == true}">{{p.name}}</div>
</ng-container>
```

update products with `favourite` when you receive from api.

Comment: same question that i asked @Suresh Kumar Ariya

Comment: Yes, it will call `getClass` function whenever `products` list is being updated.

Comment: yes, but my problem is that maybe "products" will load before "favoriteList". and than the function "getClass" will always return false. because "favoriteList" is still empty

Comment: so initialize `favoriteList` in constructor as blank. And whenever you are getting result for favList from api reassign products list from existing. It will work.

Comment: You can do it in another way as well, add `favourite` in product object when you receive data from api.

Answer (score 0):

Might been an issue with the ngClass Syntax. Here is the stackblitz code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3zfrrs

Comment: thanks! but when the "check()" will call? while the page loading? i asking because my list come from a server during the page load. so if the "check()" function will call before the list will be ready, it's will not work well